# Magento : Hide Element if Div is Active

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I have dynamic page on my site and would like to hide an element if another element is active on page. My code below and it is not working for me.

HTML code

```
<tr class="sample-details">
    <td class="a-right" style="" colspan="3">
        Sample Text
        <br>
    </td>
    <td style="" class="a-right last">
        <span class="price">$5</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<ul class="wpu">
    <li>
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="ordercomment-comment" class="required"><em>*</em>Warehouse Pick-up</label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <textarea id="ordercomment-comment" class="input-text required-entry" name="ordercomment[comment]" title="Order Comment" rows="1" cols="10" style="width:400px" placeholder="Enter Name"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code

```
if($("tr.sample.details").length) $("ul.wpu").hide();
```

Thank you

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6ygms2c/) example

Comment: This is only javascript code. Please share html also.

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?

Comment: Active: As it appears on the webpage to the customer @nuovecode Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a HTML/JS question that does not contain anything specific to Magento. Please ask it on  [so] instead.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check, if your element exist, use length. If you want to check, if it has content (whitespace counts too, maybe trim it), use html().length.

```
  jQuery(function($) {
    if ($('tr.sample-details').length) {
      $('ul.wpu').hide();
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkoepke1/7g140kjf/

There are some errors in your fiddle too. if you dont use an table tag, fiddle trims your table elements. 'tr.sample.details' just does not exists in the output and there is only the text. I dont think, requireJS is working either there. So maybe that´s why your code is not working there. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. The Magento site uses Prototype JS. How can we alter to work on that?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by active? If you mean if the element is visible (taking up space in the page) you could do something like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    if ($('.element-a').is(":visible")) {
        $('.element-b').hide();
    }
});
```

The location of the above script would depend on what module the script is part of.

Then delete `var/view_preprocessed`, delete `pub/static/frontend` and then clear all caches.

Comment: Please view the Fiddle example. How can I work properly?